# Window.onFocus vs window.addEventListener('focus'), what is the difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, window, setinterval

**I do not need help with a soloution here**

My code works but I am trying to understand the difference between two soloutions that give diffirent results even though one would think they would give the same result.

I have a page that I update using setinterval.

This page gets updated every 60 seconds(code will folow below).
I had a problem where when I changed tab and came back the page composated the missing time by updating the page multiple times.

I googled and found that detecting the focus and blur event on the window would solve my problem. This in fact did solve the problem but also created a new one.

On focus I created a new Interval:

```
 window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
                $.OverWatch.worker.setUpdateInterval()
            }, false);
```

And on blur I cleared all intervals on the page:

```
    window.addEventListener('blur', function () {
        $.OverWatch.worker.stopUpdateInterval()
    }, false);
```

This created a new issue. Once I changed the tab and came back to the page I had to wait another 60 seconds till the update took effect.

So i thought I could implement logic that updates the page on focus and creates a new interval:

**Attempt 1**

```
 window.addEventListener('focus', function () {

 $.OverWatch.worker.getView("/OverWatch/UpdateWatch", function () { // ajax updates page
       // inside of success function
          $.OverWatch.init();
          $.OverWatch.worker.setUpdateInterval()
       });

  }, false);
```

This worked but It took me back to my original problem where the browser ran the code multiple times.

After searching the web I found that i could set a function to the window.Onfocus event:

**Attempt 2**

```
    window.onfocus = function () {

        $.OverWatch.worker.getView("/OverWatch/UpdateWatch", function () {
            // inside of success function
            $.OverWatch.init();
            $.OverWatch.worker.setUpdateInterval()
        });
    }
```

This works perfectly but I don't understand why does this works without multiple page updates and not the code in attempt 1? What is the difference between these two?

Comment: You can only get one method for `onfocus` event while you can bound multiple handlers for `focus` event. `addEventListener()` add new handler, while `onfocus` overwrites any previous one bound using `onfocus` property

Comment: But I am only assigning the focus on the window object and nowhere else. 
Unless this is a effect of bubbeling?

Comment: You are probably recalling `addEventListener()` methods, maybe by nesting handlers. Now i'm just guessing because you didn't provided any MCVE (minimalistic sample replicating issue).

Comment: Well your guess ia actually correct..In my init function i made the same update call without realising it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you have easily fixed it. So i can close it as dupe for better explaination